# Как поставить фоновое изображение HTML

Tags: html, css, изображения

**Здравствуйте**. Нужно установить изображение на фон сайта. Лежит оно по пути ***"static/image/site_background.png"*** Прописываю в css файле 
`background-image: url("image/site_background.png");` 
Ничего не работает. Сайт почему-то ищет изображение по пути ***'main_page\css\site_background.png'*** (то есть в url изображения добавляет url страницы, при чём главной вне зависимости от того, на какой странице находишься). Остальные static картинки вывожу так:

```
"{% static 'image/MCStore logo.png' %}"
```

но делаю это в html файле. Пробовал применить такой способ к фону - не работает. Кто может, подскажите. Ума не приложу в чём дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В css файле нужно указывать путь к файлу картинки относительно папки, в которой находится css файл.

Comment: спасибо, получилось. А как мне указать переход на 1 папку назад? То есть выйти из папки, в которой css файл и зайти в другую?

Comment: @IIIyTH1K `background-image: url("../image/site_background.png");`